# LINQ calculate a value from 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 collections. A Dictionary containing salaries per jobgrade (`Dictionary<string, double>`) and a list of objects what contain rules (`List<jobgradeRule>`)

I want to iterate through the both lists and calculate a value based on the rule

The rule can have a `*` as the Job grade which means that all the jobgrades in the salaries dictionary should be affected.

I have this

```
    foreach (var item in salariesPerJobGrade)
        foreach (var ritem in attr)
        {
            if (item.JOB_GRADE_CD == ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD || ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD == "*")
                attrAmount += item.Value * ritem.RULE_VALUE;
        }
```

Can this be done in a LINQ statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
attrAmount += (from item in salariesPerJobGrade
               from ritem in attr
               where item.JOB_GRADE_CD == ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD || ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD == "*"
               select item.Value * ritem.RULE_VALUE).Sum();
```

And it saves you reallocating the dictionary with `ToList` call like suggested by @TJF.

Comment: I like this answer. Would this have a performance advantage over Machine Learning's answer?

Comment: They should be pretty much equal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run the code but this should get you close:

```
salariesPerJobGrade.ToList().ForEach(x => attrAmount += attr.Where(y => *check your rule here*).Sum(y => x.Value * y.RULE_VALUE));
```

Comment: Tried it out, it works. Actual statement should look like this: `salariesPerJobGrade.ForEach(item => attrAmount += attr.Where(ritem => (item.JOB_GRADE_CD == ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD || ritem.JOB_GRADE_CD == "*")).Sum(ritem => item.Value * ritem.RULE_VALUE));`